# SDL Surface with a menu and status bar

Tags: c++, sdl

How can I add a menu, and a status toolbar to SDL? I can not find any reference to this online... I think it might be an SDL limitation?

If so, what portable library can I use which would allow me to add an SDL surface to it, and a status bar and menu?

Comment: Search for any of the hundreds of [UI libraries for SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/libraries.php?order=name&category=14&completed=100&os=-1&match_name=&perpage=25).

Comment: Thanks! I feel like an idiot.